# How to group by category, but order categories depending on their lowest content?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `workTypes` and `workTypeCategories`.
workTypes contains the following fields:

- idWorkType
- code
- name
- idCategory

workTypeCategories contains the following fields:

- idCategory
- name

A workTypeCategory can have multiple workTypes as children.

Representation:

> - workTypeCategory1
>
>   - workType 1  Code 99
>   - workType 2  Code 108
>   - workType 3  Code 103
>       ------------
> - workTypeCategory2
>
>   - workType 4  Code 98
>   - workType 5  Code 102
>   - workType 6  Code 105

The thing is: right now everything is ordered by the workTypeCategory name (ASC).

I'm trying to make it so that it's sorted by the category with the lowest worktype code, but grouped by worktype category, so the same category is only shown once but the order of the categories depends on their lowest worktype code.

Here is what I have as of now, which orders by code but splits categories, outputting the same category multiple times (Which is not what I want).

```
SELECT t.code
     , t.name
     , c.name 
  FROM worktypes t
  LEFT 
  JOIN worktypecategories c
    ON c.idWorkTypeCategory = t.idCategory 
 ORDER 
    BY t.code ASC
     , c.name ASC;
```

I'm trying to be clear, I hope it is.

I'm pretty sure this is a rather simple problem, but my lack of MySQL knowledge stops me from finding the solution.

**EDIT**

Original output:

```
code    WorktypeCategory.name   worktypes.name
401     AAAAAAAA                ABC

100     BBBBBBBB                DEF
110     BBBBBBBB                FED
460     BBBBBBBB                LLL

090     CCCCCCCC                YYY
430     CCCCCCCC                ZZZ
```

Actual output:

```
code    WorktypeCategory.name   worktypes.name
090     CCCCCCCC                YYY

100     BBBBBBBB                DEF
110     BBBBBBBB                FED

401     AAAAAAAA                ABC

430     CCCCCCCC                ZZZ

460     BBBBBBBB                LLL
```

Desired output:

```
code    WorktypeCategory.name   worktypes.name
090     CCCCCCCC                YYY
430     CCCCCCCC                ZZZ

100     BBBBBBBB                DEF
110     BBBBBBBB                FED
460     BBBBBBBB                LLL

401     AAAAAAAA                ABC
```

---

## EDIT 2

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c968/2), as you can see the actual code lists the worktypes with their category name, but they're not "grouped". I want all the worktypes of category A to be together, B, C, etc. But I want these categories to be listed depending their lowest worktype code.

So right now it'd be (with the SQL Fiddle data)
A (all the worktypes under category A, in ascending order)
C (all the worktypes under category C)
B (all the worktypes under category B)
E (all the worktypes under category E)
D (all the worktypes under category D)

*** RIGHT NOW ***

```
| CODE |        NAME | CATEGORYNAME |
|------|-------------|--------------|
|  100 |      luctus |            A |
|  102 |   tristique |            A |
|  103 | scelerisque |            C |
|  111 |         sem |            C |
|  124 |       massa |            A |
|  202 |       Donec |            A |
|  300 |      varius |            B |
|  301 |      risus  |            E |
|  403 |  malesuada  |            C |
|  405 |    sagittis |            B |
|  503 |      Morbi  |            E |
|  701 |      augue  |            D |
```

***Expected output ***

```
| CODE |        NAME | CATEGORYNAME |
|------|-------------|--------------|
|  100 |      luctus |            A |
|  102 |   tristique |            A |
|  124 |       massa |            A |
|  202 |       Donec |            A |
|  103 | scelerisque |            C |
|  111 |         sem |            C |
|  403 |  malesuada  |            C |
|  300 |      varius |            B |
|  405 |    sagittis |            B |
|  301 |      risus  |            E |
|  503 |      Morbi  |            E |
|  701 |      augue  |            D |
```

Comment: try adding to your query `ORDER BY worktypecategories.name` hope this will do it

Comment: This is already in my `ORDER BY` clause. Putting `worktypecategories.name` as the primary order condition just puts me back at the original state: Everything is ordered by the category name, regardless of the code. :/

Comment: whoops sorry! my fault, i've read "where" but it was "order" - sorry for that

Comment: Having the Expected output would help me understand.

Comment: I added a few examples showing what is originally outputted, what it looks like right now and what I want it to look like.

Comment: Having two columns sharing the same column identifier in a result is a recipe for disaster! That said, I think you want "ORDER BY c.name DESC,code"

Comment: It's also a good idea to show the sample data for the expected output. The *best* thing would be to create an SQL Fiddle that we could use to recreate the issue.

Comment: @Strawberry No, the "desired output" shows a descending order for the category name simply because of the sample data I wrote, but it could be AA CCC A or BB AAA C. The only thing I was is for the categories to be listed depending on their lowest worktype code.

Comment: @McAdam331 I'm adding the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c968/2) to the post.

Comment: @JeffNoel thanks for that. This was an easy fix. In short, the order of the columns in your `ORDER BY` clause is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is really close. The problem is that you're ordering by the code and **THEN** the category name. This means that the categories aren't really going to be ordered, because the code is being ordered first.

To achieve what you want, you should order by name, and then within that group order by code, like this:

```
ORDER BY worktypecategories.name ASC, MIN(w1.code) ASC
```

Here is your [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c968/3) back with update.

**EDIT**

What I did with the following was to write a subquery that got the order of the category names we wanted (it returned A, C, B, E, D as you said) and then just joined that with the query above and it worked. Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c968/10).

```
SELECT t1.code, t1.name, t1.categoryName
FROM(
  SELECT w1.code, w1.name, worktypecategories.name AS categoryName
  FROM worktypecategories 
  LEFT JOIN worktypes w1 ON worktypecategories.idWorkTypeCategory = w1.idCategory 
  LEFT JOIN worktypes w2 ON worktypecategories.idWorkTypeCategory = w2.idCategory 
  GROUP BY w1.idWorkType
  ORDER BY worktypecategories.name ASC, MIN(w1.code) ASC) t1
  RIGHT JOIN(SELECT categoryname
  FROM(
    SELECT w1.code, w1.name, worktypecategories.name AS categoryName
    FROM worktypecategories 
    LEFT JOIN worktypes w1 ON worktypecategories.idWorkTypeCategory = w1.idCategory 
    LEFT JOIN worktypes w2 ON worktypecategories.idWorkTypeCategory = w2.idCategory 
    GROUP BY w1.idWorkType
    ORDER BY worktypecategories.name ASC, MIN(w1.code) ASC) t
    GROUP BY categoryName
  ORDER BY MIN(code) ASC) t2 ON t1.categoryName = t2.categoryName;
```

Comment: You're also pretty close, but take a look at the expected output in my second edit (the last code block). The correct order should be A->C->B->E->D. I want the categories to be displayed depending on their lowest worktype's code (so C goes in front of B because 103 is smaller than 300, but C-403 also goes in front of B-300 because ALL the worktypes within one category must be sorted together). It's hard to explain, but if you take a look at the last code block in my 2nd edit you can see the expected result.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't look that closely I'm really sorry. Let me play around with it a bit longer.

Comment: Lol, @JeffNoel not a good solution IMO but I stumbled upon this while tinkering with it. I wrote a subquery that got the order of the categoryNames that we needed, and created an outer join with my first query to this new subquery and it worked. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c968/10)

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM worktypecategories 
LEFT JOIN worktypes w1 ON worktypecategories.idWorkTypeCategory = w1.idCategory 
LEFT JOIN worktypes w2 ON worktypecategories.idWorkTypeCategory = w2.idCategory 
GROUP BY w1.id
ORDER BY MIN(w1.code) ASC, worktypecategories.name ASC
```

I simply joined twice, and grouped one of them, to obtain the lower code as an aggregate result.

Comment: Doing so only gives me one worktype per worktypeCategory, but I feel like this is getting closer to what I want, I'm forking your query at the moment to try to fix this...

Comment: You can't have one category and many types as a result, the query can return to you just rows with the same format. At most, i can give you multiple rows with the same category, one for each type, then multiple rows for the next category, etc...